# How do I launch Apache and Node in Docker?

Tags: node.js, apache, docker

I am running a Docker container based on `webdevops/php-apache` which is serving a website via Apache (based on Alpine Linux).

https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-apache.html#

I have also installed Node.js in the container, and added a vhost to Apache to run Node as a proxy at path `/node`. If I open a shell into my container and launch the Node app, I can view the app at http://localhost/node

If I add `CMD node server.js` to the Dockerfile, the container will launch with just the Node.js app at `/`. But Apache is not launched.

My question is, how do I launch Apache and Node from a Dockerfile?

Thanks!

---

Comment: Node.js contains a built-in, asynchronous I/O library for file, socket, and HTTP communication. The HTTP and socket support allows Node.js to act as a web server without additional software such as Apache. If you really need a proxy in from of the web-site, I would suggest using a dedicated container for that purpose alone. Do you have any reasons for not using the [node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) image?

Comment: When you have two separate processes like this, you'd almost always run them as two separate containers.  Docker Compose is a useful tool for managing groups of related containers, but it's not required.

Comment: @Neo thanks for the reply, yes I have reasons for not running the Node image.  Running Node alongside Apache is a thing that Apache supports, just trying to figure out how to launch this from Docker

Comment: @David thanks for the reply, for business reasons I want to run this in one container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image `webdevops/php-apache` is using `supervisord` to launch the `apache2` daemon.

If you want to have another process launched, all you need to do is to write and add a `nodejs.conf` under /opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/ in the Dockerfile and keep the same CMD from the parent image.

Here is a minimal example in which I am running both apache2 and a dummy nodejs app in the same container:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── index.js
└── nodejs.conf
```

The hello world `index.js`:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World from expressjs in a Docker container.");
});

server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

`nodejs.conf`:

```
[program:nodesprocess]
command=/usr/bin/node /index.js
directory=/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
```

And the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /
COPY index.js .
COPY nodejs.conf /opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["supervisord"]
```

To run, I am publishing both ports, the httpd and nodejs just to be easier to check from the host machine that both are running, but of course you will only publish and expose the proxy port in a real scenario:

```
// Build
docker image build -t christmastree .

// Run
docker run -p 9988:8000 -p 9987:80 christmastree:latest
```

Quick check that both processes are running: I expect to find the default apache page at `localhost:9987` and the hello world nodejs page at `localhost:9988`:

[image]

PS: I wish I was able to write in red but I can only use bold to say again that **using Docker this way is an anti-pattern**.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thorough response, was just figuring this out but you got me fully up to speed.  I agree this is not a good long term solution, its a stop gap option for us.  Have a great day!

Comment: We all face "business requirements" :). Just felt I had to write that to make other people who run into this post, aware that this is a compromise solution